# pandas astype gives a strange result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, casting

I'm trying to cast a long column (2M) of float (read as float by csv_read) into integers.

if I try to substitute the column, I get a wrong result:

```
df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']]=df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']].astype(int)
```

20190930241.0 **becomes** -2147483648

Instead, If I use applymap (elementwise) it works:

```
df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']]=df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']].applymap(np.int64)
```

20190930241.0 **becomes** 20190930241

but it's slower...

why?

Comment: Can you try df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']]=df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']].astype('int64')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system `int` is 32 bits. You can try `int64`

```
df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']]=df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']].astype('int64')
```

or

```
df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']]=df3[['DISPATCHINTERVAL']].astype(np.int64)
```